# Are Gen-Zers really a "pro-life" generation?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, abortion

Are Gen-Zers really a ["pro-life" generation](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-us-canada-60088680), or is it just a Republican trick to make their ideas look less ancient? Aren't zoomers generally supposed to be progressive (environmentalism, minority rights, and everything)? What do the polls say?

Comment: Gen Z, like any subgroup, are not homogenous and do not all share the same opinions. It may well be the case that a *majority* of Gen Z are pro-choice, but that there remains a vocal minority of pro-lifers.

Comment: This question can't really be answered as Gen-z is just an age group and as such they are across the entire political spectrum

Comment: Views on the issue are somewhat correlated to age. To make it more interesting, would be nice if someone could dig up stats that compare the opinions of gen Z vs those of other age-cohorts when they were at the same age that gen Z is now.

Comment: They are not a pro life generation as a whole in the sense of the word conservatives use it.

Comment: @PeteW The gallup poll I linked to in my answer has data by age group starting from 1975. A cursory reading suggests that older generations were also more anti-abortion in their younger years than younger generations.

Comment: I strongly disapprove of the decision to close the question (though I already got an answer, thanks @tim)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm using Gen Z to mean born 1997-2012 (i.e., currently 10-25).

Pew has data on [Views on abortion by age, 2021](https://www.pewforum.org/fact-sheet/public-opinion-on-abortion/):
[image]

We can see that generally, young people tend to support the right to abortion in higher numbers, and that the older generations get, the more they tend to oppose it. Pew doesn't have data for people <18, but 18-29 still seems well enough inside the Gen Z range for this data to be meaningful.

[Gallup](https://news.gallup.com/poll/246206/abortion-trends-age.aspx) has polls by age group over time (from 1975 to 2021) which shows the same trend (younger generations tend to have more support for the right to abortions than older ones).

The Christian and anti-abortion website [impact360institute](https://www.impact360institute.org/articles/only-29-of-gen-z-believe-abortion-is-morally-wrong/) also makes the claim that "only about 3 in 10 (29%) of Gen Z believe that abortion is morally wrong, a lower percentage than the Millennials before them".

Comment: Wait, an anti-abortion rights website is claiming that young people do not believe that abortion is wrong? Wouldn't it be more helpful for them to claim the opposite (even if it is not true)? Surely telling people that your beliefs are increasingly unpopular is not an effective persuasive strategy.

Comment: Anyway, one thing to note is that the manner in which these questions are framed can have a substantial influence on the results. For instance, asking people whether abortion is morally wrong can get a lot of people to answer "no" who think that abortion is fine, but who dislike it after three months, after six months, after nine months, after neural activity, after the fetus looks sufficiently cute on an ultrasound scan, whatever. Conversely, other ways of framing it might decrease apparent support for abortion rights ("Should abortion be legal in all cases?" "Is abortion morally right?")

Comment: @Obie2.0 they are using it as a call to action for their followers (~'things are getting worse, we need to *do* something against it'). And sure, it's somewhat of a nuanced issue (the gallup poll differentiates between 'legal under [any/certain/all] circumstances', with 19-29 year olds being esp. over-represented for the "all" option). But in either case we can see a general trend that doesn't seem to support the idea that gen z is especially anti-abortion.

Comment: The gallop poll also contains "Trends in Preferred Abortion Label", with the younger generation labeling themselves as 'pro-choice' in higher numbers (there has been a slight dip in 2021, but it's still more pro-choice / less "pro-life" than millennials.